# "Wick rotation" of tropical geometry

Tags: tropical-arithmetic, euler-characteristics

This question is related to [my earlier, even more open-ended question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/406/how-is-tropicalization-like-taking-the-classical-limit) on tropilcalization.  I will give some background and ask my question at the end.

On **R**, consider the family of commutative, associative operations ⊕<sub>*h*</sub>, indexed by positive *h*, given by *x* ⊕<sub>*h*</sub> *y* = -*h* ln( exp(-*x*/*h*) + exp(-*y*/*h*) ).  For *h*>0, the semigroup (**R**,⊕<sub>*h*</sub>) is isomorphic to the normal additive groupsemi (**R**<sub>>0</sub>,+).  But as *h* → 0, for fixed *x* and *y* we have the limit *x* ⊕<sub>*h*</sub> *y* → min(*x*,*y*).  This defines the *tropical addition*, and it's conventional to include the additive unit ∞ = -*h* ln(0).

There is a continuous/integral version of the observation that in the limit, + (in the guise ⊕<sub>*h*</sub>) becomes max.  Indeed, let *f* : **R**<sup>*n*</sup> → **R** be a continuous function bounded below, and assume that *f* grows to +∞ in all directions, fast enough so that for any *h*>0, the integral ∫<sub>**R**<sup>*n*</sup></sub> exp(-*f*(*x*)/*h*) *dx* converges (or anyway for *h* small enough; if it converges for any *h* then it does for all smaller *h*, and to converge for small *h* requires only very mild growth rates; as |*x*|<sup>ε</sup> for ε>0 is certainly good enough).  Then asymptotically as *h* → 0, the integral is supported at the (or, rather, in a formal neighborhood of the) globally-minimal values of *f*.  To make the correspondence explicit, note that ∫<sub>**R**<sup>*n*</sup></sub> exp(-*f*(*x*)/*h*) *dx* is (exp of -*h*<sup>-1</sup> times) the "⊕<sub>*h*</sub> integral" of *f*, whereas the "⊕<sub>0</sub> integral" of a function is its global minimum value.

There is another fact about asymptotic integrals, related by "Wick rotation", which is what the physicists call it any time you switch a variable from pure-real to pure-imaginary.  As above, let  *f* : **R**<sup>*n*</sup> → **R** continuous and growing reasonably quickly to infinity, but this time for real non-zero *h* consider the integral ∫<sub>**R**<sup>*n*</sup></sub> exp(-*f*(*x*)/(*ih*)) *dx*, where *i* = √-1.  The integral never converges absolutely (and so does not exist in the sense of Lebesgue), but it converges conditionally as a Riemann integral, e.g. if *f* is differentiable and given mild conditions on the growth of the norm of the derivative.  (If *f* grows at least as fast as |*x*|<sup>1+ε</sup>, we're fine, I think.)  In any case, let's assume that the integral converges conditionally for small enough (real, non-zero) *h*.  Then the method of stationary phase shows that asymptotically, the integral is supported at (formal neighborhoods of) critical points of *f*.

My question is this:  Is there a version of "tropical arithmetic" like the operation ⊕<sub>*h*</sub> defined above but related to the Wick-rotated integral?  The most naive approach, replacing *h* by *ih* and so considering *x* ⊕<sub>*ih*</sub> *y* = -*ih* ln( exp(-*x*/*ih*) + exp(-*y*/*ih*) ), is not defined because of the problem of picking a branch of the logarithm.  But perhaps this problem can be fixed for small *h*, or by approximating each pure-imaginary *ih* by *ih*+ε for some very small positive ε?  Put another way: what is the operation on numbers that corresponds to {critical points} in the same way that min(*x*,*y*) corresponds to {global minimum}?

Comment: Related question: to what extent can we extend $x \oplus_h y$ to complex-values of $x,y$?

Comment: Where is the geometry, as suggested in the title?

Comment: @Scott: perhaps "tropical-arithmetic" is a better tag?  I think I'm almost but not quite able to make new tags, but I might be misremembering the cut-off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been very little activity on this question, so I'm going to take it off the unanswered list.  In particular, in [a related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4228/), kilimanjaro linked to [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.GM/0507014), which answers some of my questions and includes many references.